# Bootstrap 5 in Angular No acces to jumbotron

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5

I'v juste create a fresh install of Angular and I install bootstrap5 with the command :

```
npm install bootstrap -save
```

After that, I'v change the lines in the angular.json for :

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

I can see that my boostrap work with the add of a button with the class btn. BUT I can't use the class .jumbotron .... I just cant't understand what is going on .... some one have a clue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, Jumbotron is not included to bootsrap 5, as a way you can add this style to style.css

```
.jumbotron {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-radius: .3rem;
}
```

or you can downgrade the version of bootsrap to 4

Comment: Yes! You are right! I lost so much time for nothing ...! haha god ... Thanks for the right infos!!!